# Значение слова "артикуляция"

Tags: значение-слов

Словари связывают это слово с речью и звуками. Кажется, никаких иных значений и быть не может.

Но откуда ноги растут у "точек артикуляции", упоминаемых, когда речь заходит о коллекционных игрушках, имеющих шарниры? Почему солидные магазины в описание товаров включают пункт "количество точек артикуляции"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Медицинский словарь дает два значения.

Артикуляция (Articulation)
1. В анатомии - точка или тип соединения двух костей. См. Сустав. 2. Совместная деятельность голосовых связок, языка, губ и других органов для членораздельной речи.
Источник: "Медицинский словарь"